# Passing form collection with Knockout.js in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I am new to MVC and I am trying to create an application with Knockout.js to send data back to the server dynamically. I am following an example i found at:

http://www.mytecbits.com/microsoft/dot-net/knockout-js-and-bootstrap-with-asp-net-mvc-part-2

It works perfectly off the site, but i am trying to send data to multiple models instead just one as in the example

The Knockout code used in the example to send the data back to the server is

```
var urlPath = window.location.pathname;
var CreateArticleVM = {
    Title: ko.observable(),
    Excerpts: ko.observable(),
    Content: ko.observable(),
    Test: ko.observable(),
    btnCreateArticle: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlPath + '/Create',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ko.toJSON(this),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(result) {
                window.location.href = urlPath + '/';
            },
            error: function(err) {
                if (err.responseText == "success") {
                    window.location.href = urlPath + '/';
                }
                else {
                    alert(err.responseText);
                }
            },
            complete: function() {}
        });
    }
};
ko.applyBindings(CreateArticleVM);
```

How do i modify the above code to be able to accept a FormCollection? Or what is the best solution to my problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Say your service is expecting more than one argument like following.

```
[HttpPost]
public String Create(ModelA modela, ModelB modelb)
{
      //Server code.
}
```

In order pass the data for Create method from client side you need to form your postdata as follows.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: urlPath + '/Create',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {modela: { "modela data in the expected form" }, modelb : { "modelb data.." } },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(result) {
                window.location.href = urlPath + '/';
            },
            .
            .
            .
            .
});
```